# Export HTML with CSS to PDF script

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

Is there a way to turn HTML + CSS code into a pdf so it does not look like printing a webpage?

So far I have been exporting my pages to pdf using `page-break-before` and the likes from the browser. But I get awful margins and it is far too browser specific. I am looking for the same look and feel you get from Latex or Powerpoint presentation exports: well centered, proper margins, custom page size.

Any idea of a script that exports a properly formatted html page to pdf?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's too wide a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tool called **wkhtmltopdf** that will convert HTML and CSS to PDF with a simple command line call. This tool can be used manually or placed in a script of some sort to run with a button click or what have you. I've used it in PHP like so:

```
$cmd = "/path/to/wkhtmltopdf /path/to/sourceHTML.html /path/to/outputPDF.pdf";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

It's very easy to use and extremely powerful for creating reports. You can download it here:

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 0):

You might try LibreOffice, but results may vary.